В посте выводится другой вид списка, чем в редакторе wordpress
Стиль списка в редакторе wordpress не так отображается, как в постах.
Я понимаю, что это где-то скрыто в стиле темы, но найти не могу.
Вот так он выглядит в редакторе

Вот так он выглядит в посте

Не могу найти в теме, как изменить. Пробовал добавить дополнительные стили списка - не читает. Пробовал как-то через !important назначит приоритет новых стилей - не работает.
Может есть просто возможность как-то по дэфолту отображать? Всем спасибо!
Сслыка на пост: https://razmowa.pl/metod-izucheniya-inostrannyh-yazykov-nikolaya-zamyatkina-kniga-vas-nevozmozhno-nauchit-inostrannomu-yazyku/

Вероятнее всего, вы сами в стилях вашей темы где-то переопределяете свойства вашего списка. Заглянул в инспектор и нашел два свойства, которые меняют вам отображение списка, причем находятся они в разных файлах.


Предполагаю, что это могут быть инлайн стили внутри текущей страницы, а также стили вашей темы. Проверьте, если проблема решилась, то не возникла ли новая проблема на других страницах, не зря же вы эти стили поставили.

Там, где в коде файл "78d301...." - это я делал дублирование сайта, чтобы поиграться с дизайном и искать, где косяк.
А вот где первая переменная, если я правильно понял, это уже код в самом посте.
А я вот ищу, где глобально менять. Т.к. в каждом посте тяжело менять каждый раз код Да и не всегда получается, когда где-то главный  стиль противоречит стилю в посте и все съезжает(
